# CSS not cascading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, css-cascade

This is part of the usersettings.css.erb with line numbers

```
11    #userSettingMain .form-horizontal .controls {
12    
13      margin-left: 30px;
14    }
15    
16    #user_birthday_3i{
17    
18      margin-left: 0px;
19    }
```

however, when I go to the page it renders the first rule and not the last, when I inspect

[image: chrome inspect]

the html is a form with .form-horizontal which has a select_date tag for choosing a date for the user birthday. the html that rails generate gives the day number #user_birthday_3i

what did I miss in this?

Comment: css rules: if 2 or more rule sets have conflicting settings, the more "specific" rule will take precedence. in your case, that's the `#userSettingMain .form-horizontal .controls` once, since that's more specific on the match rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS being cascading isn't about which rules come first, it's about [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). The `#userSettingMain .form-horizontal .controls` rule is more **specific** than the `#user_birthday_3i` rule, in the manner that it has more selectors (covering more 'depth' in the object tree) thus it overrides it.

If you really want the second one to override the first, add `!important` to the end of the `margin` definition:

```
#user_birthday_3i {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: isn't an id that is the most inner and unique in the page the most specific?

Comment: @RailsN00b Nope. `#userSettingMain .form-horizontal .controls` says: *oh hey, CSS selector engine, come here.* Look for an element with an ID `userSettingMain`, then look at children of that element that have a classname `form-horizontal` **then from those** look at the children with classsname `controls`. The other rule only looks for elements with a specific ID.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `!important` to ensure the margin you set is used.

```
16    #user_birthday_3i{
17    
18      margin-left: 0px !important;
19    }
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't cascade in the order that things are declared, they cascade down increasing specificity. So, your `#userSettingMain .form-horizontal .controls` rule is more specific than your `#user_birthday_3i`, which means it picks the more specific one.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity for the rules on how specificity is calculated.